# Python: Given the substring offset and length, find the substring index in the tokenized string list

Tags: python, string

Given a string text and given the offset and lenght of a substring in the text, I want to find the substring index in the tokenized string list.
For example, given a string text:

```
'Anarchism is an anti-authoritarian political and social philosophy'
```

and given the offset 16 and the length 18, we can know this substring is

```
'anti-authoritarian'
```

After tokenizing this text, we get the tokenized string list :

```
['Anarchism', 'is', 'an', 'anti-authoritarian', 'political', 'and', 'social', 'philosophy']
```

I want to find the index of the substring `'anti-authoritarian'` in this list(it should return 3 for this example).  We cannot use `list.index()` function because the same substring may occur several times in the text. How can I get the the substring index in the tokenized string list given the offset and length of the substring in the original text?

Comment: What about having list/dict that holds the start position of each word?

Comment: The length (18 in this case) is redundant (and could introduce errors). Only the index is required, and the word would be til the next space.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually my text is very long and the same word may occur many times and we don't know which one we need to index(may not be the first time it shows in the text). We need to use the offset to get the word.

Comment: Thanks, we are given the length(although it might be redundant and we won't use that)@CristiFati

Comment: Thanks!  Each word may occur many times in the text, how to hold that list/dict?@bgmoshe

Answer (score 0):

You can count your way there:

```
text = 'Anarchism is an anti-authoritarian political and social philosophy'
offset = 16
tokens = ['Anarchism', 'is', 'an', 'anti-authoritarian', 'political', 'and', 'social', 'philosophy']
token_offsets = []
curr_offset = 0
for token in tokens:
    token_offsets.append(curr_offset)
    curr_offset += len(token) + 1  # the next token will be found len(token) + 1 chars later than this one
>>> print(token_offsets)
[0, 10, 13, 16, 35, 45, 49, 56]
```

`token_offsets` now holds the offsets of each word/token. If you want the offset of the token at index `3`, check `token_offsets[3]`, which is the desired `16`.